# cannot open file 'MSVCRTD.lib'

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I want to program an MFC application in visual Studio 2012. I created an Empty project with just empty cpp file. when I build the project I will get this error message

```
 error LNK1104: cannot open file 'MSVCRTD.lib'  C:\Users\maj\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\MFCWindowDemo\MFCWindowDemo\LINK
```

I set the   "Additional Library Directories" in Linker of Project property to the path of lib file

```
    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\lib
```

but when I checked the path there was no MSVCRTD.lib in it. so what should I do for that?

I have Visual studio 2008, 2010 and 2012 installed together, all of them are installed in order.

Comment: have you installed MFC? its not installed by default in VS2012

Comment: normally when you install, the correct paths will be setup by the setup.exe so you should not need to set it manually. If you create a MFC program all the necessary libraries should already be setup.

Comment: Not that many programmers left that still use a 32-bit operating system.  Surely you meant to use C:\Program Files (x86) where VS2012 is installed.  Otherwise the hazard of not using a project template.  If not, well, msvcrtd.lib should certainly not be missing from vc/lib, hard to guess why it did not install properly, or got deleted, when you don't tell us anything about your machine.

Comment: @ Anders K: even win32 application C++ projects give me the same error

Comment: Sounds like you need to reinstall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just 
1-uninstalled Visual Studio 2012, 
2- deleted Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0 Folder on Program files
3- deleted HKey_LOcal_Machine\Software\microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0 tree node in registery
4- Installed Visual Studio 2012

the problem solved

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem with Visual Studio 2017.

I had to install few of the missing packages in VS 2017 for C++ Desktop development:

[image: VS 2017 Packages for C++ Development]

Answer (score -1):

All it took for me on VS17 15.9.1 was to add C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\ to my OS path. I tried adding some of the optional packages above and that didn't work.